# How to load webView once in ListView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a listView that contains a list of `LoremText` and `TestView` `UIViewRepresentable`.

I need to load in `makeUIView` of `TestView` a webView.

Every time I scroll up and down the `TestView` is created again, what causes the `makeUIView` to be called and load again the webView.

I don't want to load the webView again and i'm looking for a way to load it only once.

Is there a way to disable the reload of the `TestView`?

This is my code:

listView:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ListView: View {
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        return List {
            LoremText()
            TestView().equatable()
            LoremText()
            LoremText()
            LoremText()
            LoremText()
            TestView().equatable()
            LoremText()
            LoremText()
            LoremText()
        }.navigationBarTitle(title)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView(title: "ListView")
    }
}
```

That contains two TestViews that conform to UIViewRepresentable:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct TestView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        print("body")
        let classicUnit = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        classicUnit.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return classicUnit
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        //
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *it supposed to be called only once* - this is incorrect assumption. List drops views that out of visible area and then recreates if one become visible again. BTW, Equatable is not for this scenario (it is used when one view replaces other in place, eg. during update), so you can drop it.

Comment: I just ran the code, adding in the missing views. MakeUIView is called twice, once for each TestView. Xcode 12, on both iOS 13.5 & 14. The code listed does not reproduce the error.

Comment: You shouldn't load data in a view. Data should be loaded in a model and the model passed to the view.

Comment: Ok, thanks so Equatable is not connected.
I understand the recreation of the visible view, but is there a way to load it outside of the list and add it in a way it will not be loaded again?
Maybe saying i'm loading data was wrong. I'm loading a webView and I don't want the webView to load again every time I scroll.